# Binance API transaction history

Tags: binance

I am trying to display a users transaction history in Binance, including fund deposits and withdrawals as well as buying and selling of different crypto's. Does anyone know which Binance API endpoints I would use to do this? It seems quite complicated in comparison to other trading platforms.

This is the link to the docs: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#withdraw-history-supporting-network-user_data

I can see the Wallet endpoints "Withdraw" and "Deposit", but this won't cover crypto trading will it?, The account trade list call would be ideal, but it requires a symbol input which I'm not sure how I would obtain dynamically.

I would also like this endpoint to provide me with the data so I can get the average buy price for a crypto.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported. See: https://dev.binance.vision/t/fetch-all-account-orders/279/3

Comment: So, you have to cycle through all 1950+ symbols in order to get the entire transaction history?

Comment: Currently this is the case. Hope there working on a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the route you're looking for to get the user trade history. The big downside is that you have to specify the exchange symbol, you cannot get the history of the account with just one request:

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#account-trade-list-user_data

Answer (score 1):

Get your [account information](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#account-information-user_data) first. You can then extract non-zero balances from here to get symbols for transactions. You can then loop through each currency pair and get its [transaction history](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#account-trade-list-user_data). This seems to be the most optimistic way we can get right now

You can also try to use caching. For example, you can remember balance for a particular coin, and if it has not changed by the next launch, then it is likely (but not 100%) that no transactions were made with it

You can also connect to [WebSocket](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#payload-order-update), but this is still a terrible crutch and requires a DOS attack to get the necessary data

*Please note that here the balances for Savings wallet have LD prefix added to their ticker. For example, BTC in the Savings wallet is labeled as LDBTC*

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can get your account balance for example and filter out the non-zero ones

```
pip install python-binance
```

```
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd

api_key = "yourApiKey"
secret_key = "yourSecretKey"

client = Client(api_key=api_key, api_secret=secret_key)
account = client.get_account()

# Using dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(data=account["balances"])
df['free'] = df['free'].astype(float)
df = df[df['free'] > 0]
print(df)

# normal
for bal in account["balances"]:
    if float(bal['free']) > 0.0:
        print(f"{bal['asset'].ljust(10, '-')} {float(bal['free']):.3f}")
```